# Using Karabiner-Elements on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts-app

I want to control volume and brightness using a non-Mac keyboard.  I found an answer on Stack Exchange, which recommended Karabiner-Elements as an app that will let you do such things:
[Bind Volume controls to non-Apple keyboard without 3rd party software on macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245347/bind-volume-controls-to-non-apple-keyboard-without-3rd-party-software-on-macos-s/245384#245384?newreg=08d484f082e646b2b86ddb95902a0617)

Using Karabiner-Elements I am able to bind volume and brightness controls to the function keys as expected.  HOWEVER, the down side is that every one of my previously defined keyboard shortcuts is disabled whenever Karabiner-Elements is running.  For example, Cmd+Tab is the usual shortcut for opening the floating app switcher but it is disabled.  I had earlier set up Alfred to toggle on when I press Cmd+Space, and it is also disabled.  As soon as I quit out of Karabiner-Elements they are all restored.

I know you can go out on the internet and import shortcuts to Karabiner-Elements, but I really just want to find a way to keep my old shortcuts and just add some function key behavior.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How did you setup the non Karabinier shortcuts. (As a note I use a  corsair keyboard with no extra driver and the volume scroll just worked)

Comment: @mmmmmm Well, for example, the Cmd+Tab shortcut automatically opens the floating app switcher on an Apple, and that continued to work with my Red Dragon keyboard until I opened Karabiner-Elements.  Same for Cmd+Space for opening Spotlight.  Most other shortcuts are set in the apps themselves.

Comment: I have Karabiner and those keys work as normal. What does running Karabinier-Eventviewer show as the key events that happen

Comment: @mmmmmm Cmd is down {"key_code":"left_command"} and Tab is down {"key_code":"tab"}. Space bar is down {"key_code": "spacebar"}

Comment: Try cmd-space and cmd-tab They should show the space or tab key plus flags like left_command

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, I'm sorry I missed it the first time because the print was smaller below.  I get exactly what you suggested I should in your comment when I hold down Cmd and Tab at the same time.  The left_command key press has a left_command flag, and then when I also press the tab key I get tab with the left_command flag.

Comment: What mappings have you made in Karabinier - If only volume then pasting in ~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json would be useful